# IntelliJ Idea Community Edition - Quick Documentation Lookup

Tags: eclipse, ide, intellij-idea

Just testing out different IDEs to find my favorite for java programming.
I think IntelliJ Idea is quite cool, but i have a little problem with the quick documentation lookup.

I don't get it, how i could get the javadoc for an constructor of a class.
Here are some pictures, that should describe my problem:

If I want to get information of the constructor of a class I get only some general information of it.

[image: 1]

So, how could I get the description of an constructor like in Eclipse ?

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ display class JavaDoc, not constructor JavaDoc in this case. `BufferedImage` has several constructor and IntelliJ insists on first choosing which constructor you want. Once you complete the whole call:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(10, 20, 0);
```

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> will show this particular constructor pop-up. I must admit Eclipse is a bit more intuitive here.